# Gravity Forms - RMA Count

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I am new to Wordpress so was wondering if anyone can help?

I am creating a returns form through Gravity Forms. However, at the top of each form, I want to display a returns form number e.g RMA001, RMA002 etc. I'm thinking this could probably be done using some coding but have no idea how to code.

Please could you let me know how to do this and explain where I would need to add the code. Basic straight forward English would be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks soooo much!

Ben

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to use the [gform_pre_render](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/) hook.

I once did something similiar to this on a real site.

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_render', 'show_content_before_fields' );

function show_content_before_fields( $form ) {
 $custom_field = new GF_Field_HTML(); // temporary field object to hold our custom html
 $custom_field->id = 0; // maybe unnecessary, can't remember if really needed
 $custom_filed->visibility = 'visible'; // maybe unnecessary, can't remember if really needed
 $custom_field->content .= '<h3>RMA' . $form['id'] . '</h3>'; // The actual custom html content
 array_unshift( $form['fields'], $custom_field ); // Adds the custom field before the fields added in the form editor

 return $form; // give the form back to Gravity Forms and let it continue it's doings
}
```

This code just adds arbitrary html code to the top of the fields list. The html doesn't (shouldn't) show up in the event entries / email notifications.

You should be able to toss this into your theme's functions.php or into a site-specific plugin.

Comment: Hey Antti - I have a similar question -  I created a variable `$rma_number = 'FP-' . date("mdy") . '';`, and appended it to the `$form` array, but it won't show up on the back end of the submission. How would I go about doing that?